# How to change variables or texts in ktor frontend

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I am trying to build a simple website with ktor.

I want to add a button with a simple onClick method / Click listener. The purpose is to update a text or a list.

I tried both, the kotlinx / html dsl and freemaker. But nothing works.

Here is the Kotlinx way:

```
div("charityWrapper") {
              for(charity in charities) {
                    span {
                        text(charity)
                           }
                      }
                  }
    button {
             text("Next")
              onClick = "Hello"
           }
```

But the onClick cant do anything. So i dont know how to change the text above or the list of charities.

And this is my FreeMaker file:

```
<#-- @ftlvariable name="data" type="com.example.IndexData" -->
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>huhu</h1>
        <h2>dhesfes</h2>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="console.log('hello')">Delete kweet</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

But i dont know how to call a Kotlin function on it or change the charities..

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
input(InputType.submit)
```

for submit any to your server

```
form("/v1/settings", method = FormMethod.post) {
                        input(type = InputType.text, name = "key")
                        input(type = InputType.text, name = "value")
                        input(InputType.submit)
                    }
```